# Filtering CSV data into multiple separate files

Tags: awk, grep, csv

I have a CSV file named `file1.csv`:

```
something;AD;sss;Andorra;nothing;type_1;sss
something222;AD;sss222;Andorra;nothing222;type_2;aaa
thing;NL;thing3;Netherlands;thing;type_2;bb
etc;US;etc;United States;etc;type_2;nothing
```

I want to create separate files for each country. I make greps like that:

```
grep -e "\;AD\;.*\;Andorra\;" file1.csv > fileAD.csv
grep -e "\;NL\;.*\;Netherlands\;" file1.csv > fileNL.csv
grep -e "\;US\;.*\;United\sStates\;" file1.csv > fileUS.csv
```

This works, but I have all countries in the world, and I don't want to write these lines for every country. Is there any other solution?

I also have a column with `type_1` and `type_2`. I need to take this into account. After all the files corresponding each country are created, I need to create new files for every country with just `type_1` and new files with just `type_2`.

For example, for Andorra, I need the files:

- `fileAD.csv`:

  ```
  something;AD;sss;Andorra;nothing;type_1;sss
  something222;AD;sss222;Andorra;nothing222;type_2;aaa
  ```
- `fileADtype_1.csv`:

  ```
  something;AD;sss;Andorra;nothing;type_1;sss
  ```
- `fileADtype_2.csv`:

  ```
  something222;AD;sss222;Andorra;nothing222;type_2;aaa
  ```

I think that is ok to look just for the column with the abbreviation, but I wanted the two columns, the one with `AD` and the one with the full name `Andorra` for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the data is *simple* CSV data, i.e. that no field contains embedded delimiters or newlines:

```
awk -F ';' '
    {
        print > "file" $2    ".csv"
        print > "file" $2 $6 ".csv"
    }' file1.csv
```

This prints each line twice, once to the file given by only the second field's value, and once to the file given by the combination of the second and sixth field's value.  Each output filename will be prefixed by the string `file` and suffixed by the string `.csv`, as per the text in the question.

No validation is done of the values of the two fields used in the filenames.

If you want to incorporate the country name from the fourth field:

```
awk -F ';' '
    {
        print > "file_" $2 "-" $4        ".csv"
        print > "file_" $2 "-" $4 "_" $6 ".csv"
    }' file1.csv
```

For the given data, this would create the following files

```
file_AD-Andorra.csv
file_AD-Andorra_type_1.csv
file_AD-Andorra_type_2.csv
file_NL-Netherlands.csv
file_NL-Netherlands_type_2.csv
file_US-United States.csv
file_US-United States_type_2.csv
```

The above would work well on a system using GNU `awk`.  Other `awk` implementations may run into issues with keeping too many files open for writing at once.  On such `awk` implementations, you will have to be smarter and remember to close the files after writing to them.  Once a file is closed, one has to remember to print with `>>` the next time data should be written to the file, or else the file would be truncated.

```
awk -F ';' '
    function do_print(name) {
        if (seen[name] == 1) print >>name  # append to file
        else                 print  >name  # first write, truncate file
        close(name)
        seen[name] = 1
    }
    {
        do_print("file_" $2 "-" $4        ".csv")
        do_print("file_" $2 "-" $4 "_" $6 ".csv")
    }' file1.csv
```

This would also make the code work with `awk` on OpenBSD, with which you can't `print >` to an expression.

---

Extra (just for fun): Making the `awk` code output some statistics:

```
awk -F ';' '
    function do_print(name) {
        if (seen[name] > 0) print >>name  # append to file
        else                print  >name  # first write, truncate file
        close(name)
        seen[name]++
    }
    {
        do_print("file_" $2 "-" $4        ".csv")
        do_print("file_" $2 "-" $4 "_" $6 ".csv")
    }
    END {
        for (name in seen)
            printf "Wrote %d lines to \"%s\"\n", seen[name], name >"/dev/stderr"
    }' file1.csv
```

This writes some statistics to the error stream at the end of the processing.  For the given data:

```
Wrote 1 lines to "file_NL-Netherlands.csv"
Wrote 1 lines to "file_US-United States_type_2.csv"
Wrote 1 lines to "file_AD-Andorra_type_1.csv"
Wrote 2 lines to "file_AD-Andorra.csv"
Wrote 1 lines to "file_NL-Netherlands_type_2.csv"
Wrote 1 lines to "file_US-United States.csv"
Wrote 1 lines to "file_AD-Andorra_type_2.csv"
```

Comment: May it be a good idea to close the files after writing to them? Probably not for performance, but to prevent some awk implementations from error "too many open files"?

Comment: @Quasímodo GNU `awk` manages the filedescriptors in an intelligent way. I might add some code for `awk` implementations that are not that intelligent (and that may run out of open filedescriptors).

Comment: @Quasímodo See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, very informative.

Comment: @Kusalananda , that's really great ! Thanks for all the info

Comment: @Kusalananda, is there a way to specify a path between 'print >' and ' "file" $2    ".csv" ' ? I can't find a way to do that and all my files go in an unwanted path..

Comment: @Savas31 Just add the path so that it's part of the filename: `print > "/some/path/file" $2 ".csv"`.